# Meaning of this short quote/poem

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

I watched the movie ***Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind*** yesterday, and this quote in the movie forms the theme:

> *How happy is the blameless vestal's lot! The world forgetting, by the world forgot. Eternal sunshine of the spotless mind! Each pray'r accepted, and each wish resign'd.*
>
> -- Alexander Pope, "Eloisa to Abelard"

I get the intuitive idea behind it, but could someone help explain it in a more verbose way. I am definitely lacking context with regard to "vestal lot" and do not understand what "prayer accepted and each wish resigned" means.

Comment: This link should prove helpful, see Quora [vestal's lot](http://www.quora.com/What-does-this-quote-by-Alexander-Pope-mean-How-happy-is-the-blameless-vestals-lot-The-world-forgetting-by-the-world-forgot-Eternal-sunshine-of-the-spotless-mind-Each-prayr-accepted-and-each-wish-resignd)

Comment: @LittleEva In most cases, if you found a link that adequately answered a question, I'd encourage you to summarize and or paraphrase it in your own words *here* (as an answer), with a link back to the original source. In this case, I wouldn't recommend that, because lit-crit / interpretation of poetic, lyrical, or metaphorical language is off-topic. So I think you did the right thing by pointing OP to that site. This question will be closed soon.

Comment: Just curious, why is it off-topic for this site? My question was a sincere one and I thought english.stackexchange.com is a right place to go. (You might look at the other questions that I have asked too. They are simple and sincere).

Comment: No one was questioning your sincerity, Senthil. I think Dan was referencing the fact that pretty much any interpretation of poetry will be primarily opinion-based.  Let's wait and see what happens. But, was the link of any help?

Comment: @SenthilKumaran Eva has the right of it. StackExchange encourages objective questions, ones with factual and "correct" answers, and simultaneously discourages subjective questions, which by their nature cannot have a single "correct" answer, and boil down to opinions, politics, and ultimately a popularity contest. To learn more specifically about what kinds of questions we allow and don't, check out the [help/on-topic]. You'll see "*Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature*" explicitly prohibited as off-topic there (and now you know why it is!).

Comment: It seems to me the question is just asking for clearer exposition of the literal meaning of the text, not for any poetical or artistic opinion or analysis.

Comment: @LittleEva - Yup that link was very helpful. I read all the answers and appreciated the passage more. Thanks!.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the word _lot_ here—note that it is not “vestal lot”, but “**vestal’s** lot”, i.e., the lot of the vestal nun. _Lot_ here does not mean ‘much, many’, but refers to the nun’s lot in life, her “luck, situation, or destiny in life” ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lot), sense 1.4).

Answer (score 2):

I won't say anything more about *vestal* than you've read in the link that Little Eva provides in a comment above, except to note that one specific meaning of *vestal* (in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary) is "chaste," which in turn refers (in its simpler form) to celibacy and modesty—in the sense of purity of thought—or (in its more dedicated or extreme form) to a renunciation of physical pleasure in favor of spiritual devotion.

In the latter form of chaste devotion, according to Eloise as channeled by Alexander Pope, the relationship between the religious devotee and God yields a connection in which (as a sort of quid pro quo) God accepts every prayer from the devotee in the spirit in which it is offered, and the devotee ceases to wish for material things.

For a little background on why Eloise and Abelard are far apart and what they talk about in their letters to one another, see the Wikipdia articles on [Peter Abelard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Abelard) and [Héloïse d'Argenteuil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9lo%C3%AFse_d%27Argenteuil).